# Flutter: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm doing a Flutter course and we are currently looking at Firestore/Firebase.

In the tutorial for a simple community board, the online instructor uses a version of Dart/Flutter which is a little earlier than the one I am using (I'm using the latest V1.22.6).  The out put will put a title, description and timestamp on cards in a ListView

In the Firestore DB, one of the documents has a timestamp field and the other two do not. This exercise was to show how to return a null value or nothing if it doesn't exist.  He fixes this by a piece of code so that it just returns nothing on the card:

```
 Text((snapshot.documents[index].data["timestamp"] == null) ? "" :
snapshot.documents[index].data["timestamp"].toString())
```

With the updates to the SDK, I have fixed the syntax, but it won't print null or anything, it just falls flat with the error 'Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform'.  I'm wondering if there's a workaround so that if there's a bunch of documents in a Firestore DB and for whatever reason a field does not exist in the document, what is the best way just to print nothing on the card?

My code with the updated syntax:

```
Text((snapshot.docs[index]['timestamp'] == null) ? 'N/A' : 
                snapshot.docs[index]['timestamp'].toString())
```

The error stack:

```
The following StateError was thrown building CustomCard(dirty):
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

#0      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findKeyValueInMap
package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/…/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:82
#1      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findComponent
package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/…/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:100
#2      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get
package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/…/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:115
#3      DocumentSnapshot.get
package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:45
#4      DocumentSnapshot.[]
package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:52
...
```

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════